# How to keep link title attribute with jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Using `Jsoup.clean()`, jsoup turns the `title` attribute of a HTML link from:

```
<a href="" title="test &lt;br /&gt;">TEST</a>
```

into:

```
<a href="" title="test <br />">TEST</a>
```

This is the demo application:

```
Whitelist whitelist = new Whitelist();
whitelist.addTags("a");
whitelist.addAttributes("a", "href", "title");

String input = "<a href=\"\" title=\"test &lt;br /&gt;\">TEST</a>";
System.out.println("input: " + input);
String output = Jsoup.clean(input, whitelist);
System.out.println("output: " + output);
```

which prints:

> `input: <a href="" title="test &lt;br /&gt;">TEST</a>` 
>   `output: <a href="" title="test <br />">TEST</a>`

I tried to add `OutputSettings` with `EscapeMode`:

```
OutputSettings outputSettings = new OutputSettings();
outputSettings.escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
```

`EscapeMode.base` and `EscapeMode.extend` have no effect. `EscapeMode.xhtml` prints the following:

> `input: <a href="" title="test &lt;br /&gt;">TEST</a>` 
>   `output: <a href="" title="test &lt;br />">TEST</a>`

Any idea how jsoup does not manipulate the `title` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue/behavior: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/684 (marked as "won't fix" by the *jsoup* team).

> There's not a bug here.
>
> When serializing (i.e. in your example when you're printing out XML/HTML), we escape as few characters as necessary. That is why the > is not escaped to >; because it's in a quoted attribute, there's no ambiguity that it's closing a tag, so it doesn't get escaped.

Comment: Do you know, is there a workaround or hack I can suppress that behavior?

Comment: @flavio.donze - No, unfortunately not, I can not think of any workaround for this, aside patching the JSoup itself, or post-processing the output.

Comment: ended up patching... API would be great, maybe setting own custom EscapeMode.